# Whoa! What is this "Linked" thing?

Tags: support, linked-questions

As per the title, what is this new feature?

> [image]

Comment: Can you link a question to itself and have it show up in the list? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48076/whoa-what-is-this-linked-thing

Comment: Your hand-drawn circle is not pixelated enough...

Comment: @Eric that's cause I use gimp and not MSPaint. One has antialiasing and one doesn't..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The **Linked sidebar** is very straightforward: it gathers up any links to this question provided by the community via comments, answers, or questions, and presents them in simple list format on the right-hand side of the question. It’s important to note that these links are bi-directional — that is, if another question links to this one, the link will be listed on both questions.

See [Stackoverflow Blog for new linked posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-linked-posts/)

Comment: I figured this is what it is, am I the only person that thinks things should be announced on Meta and the blog? (I didn't search the blog first, I just magically found the side bar)

Comment: @Earlz But it is on the blog...

Comment: @Earlz It was also announced on Meta - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-posts-linked-to-other-posts/47808#47808 . Very weakly announced, but announced nonetheless.

Comment: Actually... just noticed... he [announced it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36366/please-provide-a-table-of-duplicates/47807#47807) [several](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/automatically-track-referenced-questions/47804#47804) [times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40952/link-previous-questions-to-newer-duplicates/47803#47803) on meta. Kinda makes [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48087/a-better-notification-of-significant-modifications-on-the-trilogy) that much more attractive.

Comment: You can find more info on the behavior of this sidebar in [this post by Grace Note](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/470/linked-question-not-showing-up-on-sidebar/471#471).

Answer (score 4):

I guess the "Whoa" really applies to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)...

[image: Long list of linked questions]

(Ah, apparently there's [a limit of 50 links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/is-there-a-limit-on-the-number-of-links-that-show-up-in-the-linked-section/48547#48547) now.)

Comment: I think there needs to be a limit on the number of links provided. Maybe 20?

Answer (score 3):

Unintuitive as it may seem, if the question or any of its answers link to [another SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad), the link will automatically appear in the Linked sidebar.

Also, the link will work backwards - if you go to that question, you will see a link here.