# How is a "featured question" frequently asked?

Tags: discussion, site-faq, featured-tag

I am looking at the "Frequently Asked" sidebar mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50242/155556):

I noticed that there is a question there that seems very very localized (and probably not FAQ):

[image: notFaq]

**So** I click on it to check:

[image: still not Faq]

**Nope**... it is still not FAQ.

So what is it doing in the sidebar?

Comment: Other than the one I clicked on, there are a couple others (also on that list) which **are not FAQ**.

Comment: From the [featured tag-excerpt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured): "A question with this tag can be seen on the main site **in a special sidebar in the questions list** and when viewing individual questions."  So I think that's by-design, right?

Comment: @jadarnel27 so change the title of the sidebar if that is the case...

Comment: I have certainly seen more pedantic feature requests than that; go for it =)  I'd say retag this as such and make a suggestion as to what the header *should* say.

Comment: [You keep using that word... I do not think it means what you think it means.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2y8Sx4B2Sk)

Comment: @RobertHarvey there is also a link on the bottom saying `more [faq]`, which does **not** include any of those questions that are not tagged as such.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I'd like to see "Featuredly Asked"

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comments, the answer to your initial question is in the excerpt for the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag (emphasis mine):

> A special moderator-only tag to mark important meta discussions. A question with this tag can be seen on the main site, **in a special sidebar**, in the questions list, and when viewing individual questions.

So the sidebar appears to list [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts *and* [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts.

As far as changing the header text to some other than "frequently asked", I'm not convinced it's necessary.  That feature has been around [since May 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50242/what-is-frequently-asked), and I don't see a lot of confused posts on Meta about it.

And if it did change, I'm also not sure what it would be changed *to* without causing the header to be two lines* (all of the other headers in the sidebar are one line.  I'm not a UI / UX person, but that seems intentional).

<sub>*Unless we go with [Conrad Frix's idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134961/how-is-a-featured-question-frequently-asked#comment375932_134961), which I fully support =)</sub>