# The heading "Frequently Asked" on this site's sidebar is a misnomer

Tags: discussion, site-faq, featured-tag

Instead, the questions found there include the tag [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) rather than [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). Accordingly, I think either the heading should be corrected, or only true [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions should appear on the sidebar.

Comment: I've never even seen that there before... but it does appear that it's primary function is to highlight featured topics so that it's easy to find big, recent news. Definitely should be renamed (I honestly don't see any point in having a "Frequently Asked" section there if you can just go to the tab or even the tag; seems pointless).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Jeff mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177347/the-heading-frequently-asked-on-this-sites-sidebar-is-a-misnomer/177348#177348), there's a script that runs weekly to remove the [featured] tag from questions where the tag was added more than 30 days ago. Apparently, that's *not* run on MSO!

I guess that could be useful occasionally, if the intent is to just pin a link in that list (for instance, the [community-maintained change log](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)) - but in general, that's very wrong: there are only 10 slots in that list, so when *all* of them are clogged with stuff that REALLY, REALLY NEEDS EYEBALLS (...three months ago) then the actual FAQ stuff is hidden.

I've stripped *most* of these tags, so the list should return to normal soon. In the future, these WILL be stripped automatically after 30 days on MSO as well (thanks Marc!)

Answer (score 2):

It is actually correct, however, if there are too many featured questions then those overload the available space for actual faq questions.

So lobby for removal of the featured tag from old questions.

For a while we had code that forced removal of this tag after 2 months, but you'd have to ask balpha about the status of that code. Not sure it runs here on meta.so but the intent is the same.

Basically everyone thinks *their* thing is extra important, so everything gets marked "important" and then, well, here we all are.

Comment: Well, why don't you show two sidebars: one for featured questions, and another for frequently asked?  I admit though, that to compensate, another sidebar may have to be shortened, such as recent tags.

Comment: Better to just use the featured tag responsibly IMO. When everything is IMPORTANT, nothing is important.

Comment: There are only [10 featured questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured), but yes at least a couple of them shouldn't be.

Comment: @yannis 10 is a large number for this