# How long are Meta posts featured on average?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, featured-tag

Inspired by [How long does the SE team feature meta posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364883/295232)

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) questions are automatically un-[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177380/295232), but most of the times staff decides to unfeature questions manually, because more important questions need to be featured and/or they've had enough time in the spotlights. But how long are they featured exactly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be audited with the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I've written a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1415267/how-long-are-meta-post-featured) which looks at the post history to determine when a question was [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)
and when the tag was removed. On Meta Stack Exchange, the duration is [15 days on average](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1415269/how-long-are-meta-post-featured-on-average).

[image]

With the site switcher just above the results you can check other Meta sites like Meta Stack Overflow. Do note that SEDE is refreshed only once a week, on Sunday morning, so a question might be unfeatured already without SEDE knowing about this.

Comment: It's 8.85 days on **Meta**SO but [on Stack Overflow main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgKr0.png) the [query triggers a bug](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1415269/how-long-are-meta-post-featured-on-average#messages) claiming nearly 320 days.

Comment: Some posts have been featured more than once, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305560) even 7 times. I have modified your [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1415397) to include that. Not a big difference, but just enough to make the average over 16 days.