# Should the community decide which questions become hot?

Tags: discussion, support, hot-questions

Since I have been elected a moderator at [Artificial Intelligence SE](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) (about 1 month ago), I've noticed that certain questions that have high value (for our site, but not only), such as [What are the AI technologies currently used to fight the coronavirus pandemic?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18701/2444), have not become hot questions, while others, which aren't as socially relevant (or relevant to the goal of our community) as the former, such as [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18587/2444), have become hot questions. In the past, I've seen this pattern multiple times, not only on AI SE. For example, I've seen this on Stack Overflow, even recently, although I can't remember the exact title of the post, the post became hot because there were two successive statements (of the form `k++;` and `k--;`) that canceled each other. Of course, this was just a mistake of the writer of the code (i.e. those statements don't have any effect!!). Is this really a question that deserves to become hot?

This clearly suggests that the current algorithm or heuristic to determine which questions should become hot (or not) isn't working appropriately. Although I am aware of the ability that moderators have to remove a question from the hot questions list, I think this is not sufficient, in the sense that, in the case certain questions are not even considered for the hot list, they should be manually added. Furthermore, note that changing the hardcoded heuristic/algorithm doesn't improve much the situation, because, often, e.g. in the case of this coronavirus situation, the heuristic needs to change flexibly and adaptively, according to the situation, and, currently, only humans can do this (intelligently).

Therefore, I suggest the following alternative approach. There should be a separate voting system (possibly different than the current voting system, which mainly grades the quality of the question only according to the users that have seen and read the question or are specifically interested in that topic) that can be used to explicitly vote or promote a question to become a hot question. More precisely, I suggest that mainly moderators (and maybe other users) could vote for a question to become hot.

This can be especially useful for questions that don't receive answers, although they are clearly important. Furthermore, by doing this manually for several years, we could collect "good data" that could be used in the future to train a machine learning model to help to recognize actually potentially hot questions. Finally, I think that the community should decide which questions should become hot. A healthy community should be able to decide which questions actually deserve more attention.

You could argue that this new voting system is exactly similar to the existing voting system. Well, I don't see a big problem here anyway. Votes really represent the importance of the question, but, in this case, they will specifically represent something else (e.g. "Should this question attract more attention?"). In any case, I believe this will help to promote certain questions that should really be promoted to the hot list that are not currently being promoted.

This voting system would be more similar (in scope) to the voting system used to close or re-open a question rather than to upvote/downvote it.

Some people claim that this system may not scale for sites with many questions (e.g. Stack Overflow), but this is a poor argument because people already use voting systems to close questions for other types of reasons (e.g. off-topic, too broad, etc.). Furthermore, I am not saying that this voting system needs to necessarily replace the existing system. Maybe it can simply augment it. This would be an option that moderators (or other users) would further have to deal with certain relevant questions that the underlying heuristic didn't even consider (for whatever reason, but probably because it wasn't intelligent and adaptive enough to understand it).

Comment: On network-wide meta a feature request of this magnitude (introduce a whole new voting system) should, IMO, be accompanied by overwhelming evidence of the problem, not just one mod's opinion on which of their site's questions are worthy or not. For something like this to be taken seriously I'd want to see--at a bare minimum--that their own site has hashed it out thoroughly on their meta and concluded that the linked posts are desirable/not as described by OP. Consider next: there's plenty of high-quality discussions of HNQ extant on MSE already. A proposed improvement should show both...

Comment: ...that it is aware of the existing conversation and how it advances the aims and avoids the pitfalls identified therein. Lastly, this post seems to ignore the fact that the community *already decides which questions become hot*, by answering and upvoting quickly. I (personally) think there's a good conversation to be had about how well tuned the algorithm's parameters are, but this post doesn't seem to be the start of that conversation.

Comment: so is the problem a) hotness is not tracked quickly enough or b) hotness should be decided by some extra voting mechanism? I would also bump or bold the proposed solution, as it is being lost right now

Comment: i don't care much for Hot but i realize that sites want to steer visitors to "quality" content. I wonder what community decided when Hot was introduced. I can also imagine that SE, Inc has different idea about Hot page than the community

Comment: "Why not let people choose what needs attention?" - like nitsua60 mentioned earlier people do this already to some degree by upvoting the post. I'd flip this around: why are people on your site upvoting content that isn't "good", and not upvoting content that is "good"? "This can be especially useful for questions that don't receive answers, although they are clearly important." - that's what bounties are for. Why "mainly moderators"? Moderators *removing* items from HNQ was already a bit controversial when SE first added that ability..

Comment: There's been a lot of prior discussion on meta about the HNQ formula, have you read any of those? (personally I've wondered if weighting votes by site reputation might work better .. which was discussed [12 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11604/401104) .. I'm repeating nitsua's comment again but if you've read any of those it'd be useful to include that here)

Comment: Should have more upvotes, but ... It seems that they are a few *battles* that you should win first: "[What are the main problems of our Stack? What could we be doing better to grow?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/17742)", "[Are too many unanswered questions in the system?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1579/17742)", "[Is the service quality high enough?](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/17742)", etc., which you are aware of. Perhaps more usage of a **[Featured on Main](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295371/282094)** feature could *hot* it, the alg. could use that.

Comment: 'Wrong' posts showing up on HNQ is caused by incorrect voting, not by the HNQ system itself. You're suggesting to fix the wrong problem, I think. Hence the call for evidence by multiple users already.

Comment: Those issues don't have 200 views or a dozen upvotes amongst them, perhaps participation in the site's child metas is an issue common throughout most (but not all) communities that needs to be addressed; so such low participation isn't thought to be adequate. The point made in my last sentence of that comment is your road forward, despite my upvote and your upward trend you've gained further downvotes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Relevant to your meta post.

Answer (score -9):

Selection of hot questions must not only be done on voting but also based on ethics and relevance to meta thus I support a committee of moderators to sort out relevant and ethical questions from hot list and also some unpopular questions may have a comparatively high value if answered by techno wizards of this community.

Comment: Unfortunately, with thousands of questions that doesn't scale well ...

Comment: Besides, moderators are busy enough as-is.