# Make the Featuredly Asked Questions into only Frequently Asked Questions

Tags: feature-request, sidebar, meta-faq, featured-tag

Take a look at the sidebar right now on the [main page](https://meta.stackexchange.com), or look at my screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot of the sidebar, showing the featured question box and the list of Frequently Asked Questions, with some of the same links appearing in both]

Do you notice anything weird?

And how about now?

[image: Redacted screenshot of the sidebar, with red freehand circles around the featured questions, in both the featured subsection and the FAQ subsection. Freehand written featuredly in place of crossed out frequently.]

As the space for FAQ posts in the sidebar is limited to only [10 slots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295371/361484), can we please use all 10 slots for FAQ posts? The featured posts already have a very prominent place in the featured box itself. I know the featured posts are important, but not that important to kick out the FAQs and be listed twice.

Comment: In other words, deduplication?