# Featured questions in FAQ list

Tags: bug, meta, meta-faq, featured-tag

I just noticed on the sidebar of Meta that featured questions are displayed twice - once in the "Featured" block and again in the "Frequently Asked" block. The featured questions are important, but it doesn't really make sense to list them with the basic FAQ questions like "How does Reputation work?" This seems unintentional to me so I'm tagging as a bug.

[image: Meta sidebar with Featured questions appearing in FAQ]

Comment: No bug, as Shog said, that's how it always worked. Also, there's already a [feature request asking to change it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381715/make-the-featuredly-asked-questions-into-only-frequently-asked-questions).