# Sudden surge of upvotes, how to track why/where users come from?

Tags: discussion, tracking

I noticed a surge of 6 upvotes on an old answer of mine on stackoverflow.com over a weekend.  This seems unusual, provided it was just a subjective survey question, so I'm curious to know how this happened.  Did someone link to the question from a forum, causing a spike in upvoting to various answers?  Did someone point out my answer specifically?

Googling "link:URL_to_question" returned no results.

Is there any other way to satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: Could you link the question? Sometimes knowing what the answer is specifically about tends to help think about what kind of situation would promote a gathering. Still won't help if it was linked via private email or chat correspondence, though.

Comment: The question in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500607/what-are-the-lesser-known-but-cool-data-structures/562679

Comment: Ironically, posting a link here is likely to give you another boost of votes.

Comment: @Simon, but [that link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500607/what-are-the-lesser-known-but-cool-data-structures/562679) to a specific answer is a bit of a dead end, as it's missing the `#562679` fragment. ;-)

Comment: I'm a coder, not a pretentious SEO marketing consultant.  But if you want to vote me up for better karma, I won't stop you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter, [what else](http://topsy.com/stackoverflow.com/questions/500607/what-are-the-lesser-known-but-cool-data-structures)... ;-)

Looking back, things might have started [at the Hacker News homepage](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1370847), and from that three automatic ([1](http://twitter.com/hkrnws/status/14513107385), [2](http://twitter.com/hntweets/status/14513108172), [3](http://twitter.com/hnquestions/status/14514857762)) and one "Highly Influential" [tweet](http://twitter.com/the100rabh/status/14513728918), yielding more retweets and people [bookmarking it](http://delicious.com/search?p=What+are+the+lesser+known+but+cool+data+structures) at Delicious, resulting in [a tweet](http://twitter.com/delicious50/status/14553297964) by [twitter.com/delicious50](http://twitter.com/delicious50), ..., and that's [still](http://twitter.com/kashinathpai/status/14633168270) not the end to it.

And, seeing [who posted](http://news.ycombinator.com/user?id=limist) that link at Hacker News, I guess [Kai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294239/limist) is [your benefactor](http://limist.com/about/). ;-)

(And remember to append a `+` after `bit.ly` URLs to get [more details](http://bit.ly/abbYG8+).)

Comment: ...and browsing that Hacker News page, I feel it's a shame those people have not put their comments and other suggestions at the SO question!

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check the "Linked" panel on the right from within the question, to see if your answer was cited in another question on Stack Overflow.

[Linked http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/6163/lexical.jpg](http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/6163/lexical.jpg)

Comment: *slaps forehead* Somehow I never noticed that section.  Though, in my case the questions linked have had no recent activity, but it is a factor.

Comment: @spoulson: It was only added about a month ago :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48076/whoa-what-is-this-linked-thing

Comment: @spoulson: However it doesn't seem to be the case for [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500607/what-are-the-lesser-known-but-cool-data-structures/562679). Maybe someone linked to it from a blog or from some discussion board. You probably have to wait a few days until the `link:URL_to_question` returns results.