# How to make a question appear on the "Linked" list?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface

In what way may I alter the list of "Linked" questions appearing aside? Explicit links (from the question's body) are always put on the list, but these are not the only ones existing there – a few strongly related questions also appear on the list. Is it done automatically, through moderator tools, or by some other means unknown for me?

I is sometimes useful to point at a question which presents a useful example or shows the same problem from a different point of view. Also, it would be a good way to promote own questions which could enrich a discussion on other user's topics.

Comment: Those others are questions which link to this one. Nothing more complicated than that.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48077/147247 -- took me too long to find it so I can't just edit my old comment. Now go to that question and you should see this one on its linked list, except that question has too many to fit, but it is on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/48076?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linked sidebar just shows which posts have a hyperlink to or from your post

You either have to post a link on the current post to another post on the same site, or you 
could do the opposite, posting a link to your post from another post on the same site.

I don't think it's possible to manually insert a link there without actually posting a link, but unlinked questions often show up in the Related sidebar