# Demote duplicate flags to 'similarity'

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am not a high-score user on StackOverflow, so I don't know, if this feature exists for more established users. Sorry if this is a duplicate in itself.

I often come across new questions in my search scope that are quickly (and sometimes mistakenly) marked as duplicates. This is an old and discussed issue, and other questions have addressed the issue of why a duplicate is not removable in and by itself. While I agree that simply removing a duplicate flag seems like a somewhat bad idea, it seems to me, like they are dealt out too quickly nevertheless. Often a question is similar in nature, but does not cover the asked question, and even more often, the answers provided to the 'original' do not solve the issue of the OP.

How about a system, where users have the option to change a duplicate into a link instead, one that marks it as 'similar, but not the same' or - if the answers do not solve the issue of THIS question - 'not answered here'. This last option is especially relevant, if an answer to the 'original' question has been accepted, but does not solve the entire issue of OP.
In this case, the 'new' question could be edited to cover part of it by the linked question, but the more specific section should still be answered.
This should, however, be a community option, not an option for the OP. So if I find a question that is marked as duplicate, but it's obviously not, then I need that option to 'unduplicate', or at least to suggest it, and have it confirmed by other members of the community.

Answer (score 3):

I think your use case is already covered by the [Linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48076/215590) that appear in the right sidebar whenever you are viewing a Q&A using the web browser, and one or more questions have been linked from or to it.  To make a Linked question appear simply include a question link in a comment, answer or question.

I think the way Duplicates are applied now is usually fine but if you ever think two questions are only superficial duplicates then you can edit the one marked as a duplicate to explain what is different enough about it to keep it separate.  That should place it in the review queue and if the community's reviewers agree with you then they will vote to re-open it.

Comment: Does any edit place a question on review? I sometimes edit my own questions, if I spot a minor typo. If that pushes them to a separate queue that causes extra workload for others, I need to revise my asking questions...

Comment: I thought a bit about this answer, and in fact, it covers the use case per se. The system can work this way. Nevertheless, I still think, that editing the question itself and adding a 'NOT A DUPLICATE' line is a bit unwieldy. The idea is the same though, only that I suggest making this sort of a flag. I still think that the reviewers should decide, not the OP, or an initial editor.

Comment: If a question has been closed as a duplicate then an edit sends it to the review queue so the edit should be substantial - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194479/215590