# The new delete-votes limit should not apply to one's own answers

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

The [new rules for delete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010) kicked in today but they also apply to deleting one's own answers. From the discussion I gather that this new rule is intended to protect valuable questions.

As it works now it stops me from cleaning up noise and mistakes.

So, please make a distinction between deleting questions and deleting one's own answers.

Comment: looks like undelete limitation reached first and then delete limitation occurs for me, IIRC, I could delete 5 posts, but can undelete only 3.

Comment: The new delete rules are designed *primarily* to protect good *answers* on marginal questions.

Comment: @Robert: but that does not have to impede the right of the owner of an answer to delete it, right?

Comment: Agreed.  I edited the title of your question to make it clearer. Feel free to revert if you think it's wrong.

Comment: This didn't actually happen.  You ought to unmark the answer, perhaps.

Comment: @Hans: this particular 'feature' was deemed a bug and fixed. Other limits and rules (5/day) were introduced much later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct; the daily vote limit check was happening a bit too soon in our logic.

This has been fixed - when deleting your own content, the daily limits are no longer checked.

Comment: This will be pushed tonight.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm glad it's not 'by design'.

Answer (score 2):

[According to Jarrod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), the new limits only apply to deletion of other persons' posts. [Traditional limits on deleting your own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222) still apply.

Comment: Yes, that is why I used both the [bug] and [feature-request] tags. It does apply to my own answers right now.