# Is there any Stack Exchange site about book recommendations, reviews, feedbacks, etc.?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

I am looking for this, but cannot find yet. Do we have any Stack Exchange site which serves the purpose of book recommendations, reviews, analysis, feedbacks, etc.?

This would have been great, as people could discuss, or give a heads up, or just leave a good overview/feedback on a particular book that another might find interesting.

<sub>*I think I do not do bad if I ask this here; however, if this questions is not supposed to be here, kindly let me know.*</sub>

Comment: I don't think it does.

Comment: It does finally. There's the reason explained why such sites don't exist at the SE network. Probably not the answer you expected to hear, but it is like it is.

Comment: There is [literature.se] for questions about books, but we do ***not*** accept recommendation questions, or discussiony type questions like reviews or feedback. You're welcome to join [Literature chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room) for discussion with other SE users interested in books, and we also have a [community-run Tumblr](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/) for short book reviews.

Comment: @Randal'Thor but that is specifically about a *Literature* genre of the books, right? I'm looking for something about Computer Science, and Software Engineering, in particular.

Comment: Oh, if you're looking for tech textbooks, then indeed that wouldn't be on-topic for Literature. I didn't realise; "books" is pretty vague :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes, tech/science books.. it's a huge problem in reality. There are tons and tons and zillions of tons of the books.. yet I can hand-pick probably 2 or 3 I consider as a good book, worth reading. In many cases, book can even confuse the reader. So, I'm a big advocate of clean literature and education materials in CS/SE. A side note: GoodReads doesn't work well for this matter..

Comment: Good point. I think you'll have to find a forum for your questions, they're not well suited for a Q&A site. Having said that, I know of a couple of posts where it was done anyway but most of those are closed (for good reason) and out-of-date.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Some sites keep book lists and resource links on old questions or in tag-wikis. E.g. the c++ tag wiki on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related: *[What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read)* (646 answers (incl. deleted)!) and *[The Great Question Deletion Audit of 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010)*.