# Should users be able to move their answer to a more appropriate question?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions

The question [Learning Ruby (On Rails) - Need Starting Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209900/learning-ruby-on-rails-need-starting-advice) basically asks two questions:

1. Should I learn Ruby first, and then Rails, or learn them both at once?
2. What's the best way of learning about them?

Asking two questions is not ideal practice, but understandable.

The second question is (in my opinion) an exact duplicate of [Learning Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574/learning-ruby-on-rails). But the first question is possibly valid, and therefore the question as a whole shouldn't be closed.

Should answerers solely answering #2 be able to move their answers to the older question without losing edit history and voting history? I'd like to be able to downvote such answers with a comment "Please move this to the older question", and un-downvote them once they've been moved.

Answer (score 3):

Users can already do this.

Click "edit", copy the post's markup, go to the other question, post a new answer, delete the old answer.  (You can always delete your own answers unless they're accepted, in which case you can leave a comment.)  When deleting, it's useful to leave a comment with why and a link to the new answer, for moderators and 10k users.

You could even leave that comment with a link and saying you'll delete it in a few days, so anyone who comes back can easily find it.

In fact, when users take the time to maintain their answers, this works much better than merging duplicates.  (You'd usually only have to check back every once in a while, but I tend to check my posts when I notice votes or other activity anyway.)  It would be nice to see when a question you've answered gets closed as a duplicate for this reason, too.

Comment: This sounds like a good way to go and keeps with the overall StackOverflow attitude of letting the community handle things rather than hard coding a behavior pattern directly into the application.

Comment: This approach is manual and history and votes will be lost

Answer (score 1):

No please ... this would cause a huge amount of havoc and would have the potential to cause some serious confusion.