# Closing old duplicate pairs of questions?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions

## Background:

For the following older questions, I found them by using the search noted in [Let's clean up the "this is a duplicate" answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103632/152009):

[`is:answer isaccepted:1 body:"duplicate" url:"*stackoverflow.com/*"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+isaccepted%3A1+body%3A%22duplicate%22+url%3A%22%2Astackoverflow.com%2F%2A%22)

The following questions contain an **accepted answer which notes the duplicate question**.  (For simplicity, I've included the excerpt from the accepted answer in the 
first question which **may be a duplicate** of the second question.)

## My Question:

#### Are these questions too old to be closed as duplicates?  Or if not, Should they be closed? Should I *flag* question pairs like these as duplicates or not?

- There are appears to be hesitation in closing them as several have a few votes, but none have enough to close?  Some of these questions are over two years old?
- I believe that all of these questions almost exactly duplicate the questions as noted.

  - I don't think this is an [issue of different software versions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95011/152009).
  - Almost all appear to have the same level [of specificity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104877/152009).
  - The answers in the older questions still appear relevant, so I don't think they fall under [this exclusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95011/152009).
  - I think many of these could be directly merged [as recommended here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40313/152009), but I've stopped short of asking that for these.
- It appears that **most if not all of these are fairly open and shut cases** -- for all of them, the OP marked the answer (which I've linked to) as **accepted** and it contains the a note of the duplicate.
- My favorite by far is [#17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3776696/317773) which the [answerer included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776696/what-does-this-mean-within-a-class-definition/3776736#3776736):

> *Marking this as CW because it's not meant as an answer but the reason for closevoting as duplicate*

### And yet they aren't closed?

---

## Currently Open

#### 1. [Jquery: calculating width of hidden input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6908171/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [jQuery - Get Width of Element when Not Visible (Display: None)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1472303/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908171/jquery-calculating-width-of-hidden-input/6908205#6908205):

> Also, this appears to be a duplicate of: [jQuery - Get Width of Element when Not Visible (Display: None)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472303/jquery-get-width-of-element-when-not-visible-display-none)

#### 2. [to validate date in aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2169394/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [date validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2169135/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169394/to-validate-date-in-aspx/2169412#2169412):

> this is a duplicate of this question: [date validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169135/date-validation/2169263#2169263) answers there. **Edit:** duplicate in that being an aspx page really makes no difference. You can embed the code in the aspx page or better yet use a code behind class.

#### 3. [clear FileUpload object on c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1326884/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [How to prevent repeated postbacks from confusing my business layer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/481564/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326884/clear-fileupload-object-on-c/1327004#1327004):

> Here are some links: (1) [How to prevent repeated postbacks from confusing my business layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481564) and (2) [Asp.Net SQL Refresh page duplicate inserts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/743948)`

#### 4. [.NET 3.5 WinForms: Changing the value in DataGridViewComboxBoxCell modifies other ComboBox controls on the form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1757901/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [How to separate the selected item of two combobox with a single DataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729873/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757901/net-3-5-winforms-changing-the-value-in-datagridviewcomboxboxcell-modifies-other/1758027#1758027):

> [How to separate the selected item of two combobox with a single DataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1729873)  Duplicate question.  Still, this seems ridiculously stupid - we have to clone datasources for WinForms?

#### 5. [Flex: time how long HTTPService takes to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2051543/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [In Flex, is there a way to determine how long an HTTPService.send() call takes round-trip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1883668/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051543/flex-time-how-long-httpservice-takes-to-load/2057790#2057790):

> This is a duplicate, go here to see my previous answer to the question: [In Flex, is there a way to determine how long an HTTPService.send() call takes round-trip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883668/in-flex-is-there-a-way-to-determine-how-long-an-httpservice-send-call-takes-ro/1884207#1884207)

#### 6. [Unable to perfom LINQ on this XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2176533/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [My linq-query doesn't work when adding the xmlns-attribute to the root-element in my XML-document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/793580/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176533/unable-to-perfom-linq-on-this-xml/2176724#2176724):

> The issue is not with your SolutionProfile tags, but rather the presence of the xmlns attribute in it. Duplicate of an existing SO question. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793580) for the exact answer.

#### 7. [Filtering with Fiddler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4450892/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Filter Fiddler traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4098877/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450892/filtering-with-fiddler/4510075#4510075):

> Basically a duplicate of [Filter Fiddler traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098877/filter-fiddler-traffic) .  Just go to the Filters tab in Fiddler and then the "Client Process" fieldset and then choose "Show only traffic from " and choose the appropriate process.

#### 8. [Extract Json values as Map with lift-json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5571259/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Can I use the Scala lift-json library to parse a JSON into a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3843000/317773)

- Please note this case is special as the answer was written by the OP.
- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571259/extract-json-values-as-map-with-lift-json/5573311#5573311):

> Somehow I missed the duplicate of this in my search:
>   [Can I use the Scala lift-json library to parse a JSON into a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843000/can-i-use-the-scala-lift-json-library-to-parse-a-json-into-a-map)

#### 9. [MySQL - The Installation Failed on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5645038/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Re-install MySql in mac os x 10.6.6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5067787/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645038/mysql-the-installation-failed-on-snow-leopard/5651195#5651195):

> There is a duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067787) with a solution to follow [here](http://www.malisphoto.com/tips/mysql-on-os-x.html#Anchor-User).

#### 10. [Writing ALL program output to a txt file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574543/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [How can I redirect stdout to some visible display in a Windows Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/573724/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574543/writing-all-program-output-to-a-txt-file-in-c/574554#574554):

> This is a duplicate of: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573724)

#### 11. [How to create a friendly date format (for example "submitted 2 days ago")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670161/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Calculate relative time in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670161/how-to-create-a-friendly-date-format-for-example-submitted-2-days-ago/670166#670166):

> This is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

#### 12. [elisp how to check if Shift key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1477755/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Can I send a <shift> keypress to Windows from Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1043073/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670161/how-to-create-a-friendly-date-format-for-example-submitted-2-days-ago/670166#670166):

> Duplicate question (ignoring the 'Windows' part of the other one).
>
> [Can I send a  keypress to Windows from Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043073/can-i-send-a-shift-keypress-to-windows-from-emacs)

#### 13. [Jquery Update Browser Location, Don't Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1626466/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Is there a way to change the browser's address bar without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/352343/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626466/jquery-update-browser-location-dont-redirect/1626491#1626491):

> Exact duplicate of [#352343 Changing browser’s address bar without refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352343/changing-browsers-address-bar-without-refreshing).
>
> **update:** HTML5 now allows `pushState`, but only within the same domain.

#### 14. [Screen-scraping of a secure page of any site on https:// with asp.net in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2476081/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Screen scraping HTTPS using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1847710/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2476081/317773):

> See also [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847710/screen-scraping-https-using-c)

#### 15. [Verifying Mercurial Changesets are from who they say they're from](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3284642/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Verify Mercurial Checkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3237889/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284642/verifying-mercurial-changesets-are-from-who-they-say-theyre-from/3290869#3290869):

> Ry4an also pointed out this (essentially duplicate) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237889/verify-mercurial-checkins) with some good answers that confirm what I'd found elsewhere.

#### 16. [Is there a decent html editor that works in-browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3549558/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** https://stackoverflow.com/q/1505761/317773

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549558/is-there-a-decent-html-editor-that-works-in-browser/3550554#3550554):

> Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505761/textarea-with-syntax-code-highlighting
>   and [Textarea that can do syntax highlighting on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619167/textarea-that-can-do-syntax-highlighting-on-the-fly)

#### 17. [what does $this mean within a class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3776696/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [What is the meaning of $this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3696874/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776696/what-does-this-mean-within-a-class-definition/3776736#3776736):

> Please see the [PHP Manual on Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). `$this` refers to the object instance. Also see these questions:
>
> - [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)
> - [What is the meaning of $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696874/what-is-the-meaning-of-this)
>
> *Marking this as CW because it's not meant as an answer but the reason for closevoting as duplicate*

#### 18 . [XML Comments -- How (or where) do you create XML comments for your namespaces and library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6064715/317773)

**May be a duplicate of** [Namespace documentation on a .Net project (Sandcastle)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156582/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064715/xml-comments-how-or-where-do-you-create-xml-comments-for-your-namespaces-and/6068542#6068542):

> Since the question is tagged with "sandcastle", I assume you are indeed using it. If so, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156582/namespace-documentation-on-a-net-project-sandcastle) should give the details.
>
> **Update:** OK, I just ([in that same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156582/namespace-documentation-on-a-net-project-sandcastle)) saw that apparently Sandcastle understands NamespaceDoc-classes as well. Somebody might want to close this question as a duplicate.

#### 19. [Post/Redirect/Get in Webkit causes a full page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114962)

**May be a duplicate of** [Full page reload on Post/Redirect/Get ignoring cache control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3004702/317773)

- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114962/post-redirect-get-in-webkit-causes-a-full-page-reload/4895978#4895978):

> Also, this question is a duplicate of "[Full page reload on Post/Redirect/Get ignoring cache control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004702/full-page-reload-on-post-redirect-get-ignoring-cache-control)".

---

## Already Closed

#### 1. [Is there a way to identify an element on the page at a specified location in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3750877/317773)

**Closed as a duplicate of** [How do I find the DOM node that is at a given (X,Y) position? (Hit test)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1569775/317773)

- For this one, [I asked about it on Meta previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104828/152009)
- [Accepted answer notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750877/is-there-a-way-to-identify-an-element-on-the-page-at-a-specified-location-in-java/3751304#3751304):

> (This is a duplicate of [How do I find the DOM node that is at a given (X,Y) position? (Hit test)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569775/how-do-i-find-the-dom-node-that-is-at-a-given-x-y-position-hit-test))

Comment: 12. is actually not a duplicate - the linked question is about the reverse process.

Comment: 10. Also is not really a duplicate, even if the accepted answer says so. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574543/writing-all-program-output-to-a-txt-file-in-c) has two parts, one of them asking about the strange behaviour of `sOutFile << stdout;`, which is not explained in the other question.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your original questions:

- I think these should be closed, no matter how old they are.
- The hesitation to close-vote is mainly caused by people not knowing that these are duplicates ... and nobody looks at old questions.
- Whether you should flag these for moderator attention, I'm not sure. Wait for a moderator's comment. It could be that them being here already helps a lot for people to vote on them.

I'm going through the list and will vote everywhere where I think you are right.

Answer (score 1):

### About #17 ($this in PHP):

There are more similar posts.

1. [what does $this mean within a class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776696/what-does-this-mean-within-a-class-definition) (accepted answer mentions 2. and 3.)
2. [What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php) (your proposal)
3. [What is the meaning of $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696874/what-is-the-meaning-of-this) (has a close-vote to 4.)
4. [How to explain 'this' keyword in a best and simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094052/how-to-explain-this-keyword-in-a-best-and-simple-way)
5. [What does $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124982/what-does-this-mean-in-php) (closed as duplicate for 6., also a link to 4)
6. [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)
7. [$this vs function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951288/this-vs-function-name) (has an old duplicate vote to 1.)
8. [Where's the difference between self and $this-> in a PHP class or PHP method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948315/wheres-the-difference-between-self-and-this-in-a-php-class-or-php-method) (old duplicate vote for 6.)
9. [PHP: This and Self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361625/php-this-and-self) (closed as duplicate of 6.)
10. [Meaning of $this-> in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999307/meaning-of-this-in-cakephp) (links to 6.)
11. [What is $this->User a reference to within the UsersController in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999411/referencing-this-user-from-within-userscontroller-cakephp) (link to 6., old duplicate vote for 10.)
12. [Help me understand how is $this used in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581857/help-me-understand-how-is-this-used-in-php) (Has no links at all, but the accepted answer looks like a quite good explanation.)
13. [what is the function of self keyword in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858812/what-is-the-function-of-self-keyword-in-php) (closed as duplicate of 6.)

I'm not quite sure which one we should select as the canonical question/answer here.

Not a duplicate:

- [PHP this pseudo variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366129/php-this-pseudo-variable)
- [context of self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202932/context-of-self) (links to 8. and 6.)
- [$this variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855257/this-variable-in-php) (links to 6.)
- [Another way to reference $this in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607787/another-way-to-reference-this-in-php) (links to 6. in a deleted answer)
- [PHP: Does $_this have a special meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875922/php-does-this-have-a-special-meaning)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035449/why-is-oop-hard-for-me (closed as off-topic, linked from 7.)

Comment: There may be a discrepancy as to which question(s) it is closed as a duplicate of, but I don't think that's a reason not to close it.  (Several of these provide directly applicable, useful answer of questions which are essentially 98% duplicates)

Comment: Perhaps we should be more agressive in merging?